# Sens inopiné de « entendre »

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Le sens de **entendre** [ci-dessous](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1789523), diffère-t-il de celui caractéristique du verbe « ouïr » ?

> Il doit **en** être d’autant plus ainsi que le considérant 59 de la Directive 2001/29 et le considérant 23 de la Directive 2004/48 **entendent** expressément laisser au droit national des Etats membres le soin de fixer les conditions, modalités et procédures relatives à l’injonction en cause.

1. Si oui, quelle définition dans [cette entrée du Larousse](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/entendre/29878?q=entendre#29778) y correspond ?
2. Comment et pourquoi est-ce que **entendre** possède un sens si inattendu ?
3. Y a-t-il d'autres exemples de cet usage de **entendre** dans la littérature fiable et illustre ?
4. Quel est l'antécédent de **en** ? Malheureusement, je n'ai pas pu mettre la main sur l’œuvre originale (outre Wordreference) pour fournir plus de contexte.

Voici ma scrutation de la citation :

> Il doit en être +
>   d’autant `plus` ainsi que [*= all the more `in this way` as*] +
>   le considérant 59 de la Directive 2001/29 et le considérant 23 de la Directive 2004/48 +
>   **entendent** expressément laisser +
>   au droit national des États membres +
>   le soin de fixer les conditions, modalités et procédures +
>   relatives à l’injonction en cause.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ici **entendre** a le sens de **vouloir**.

Entendre vient du latin *intendere* qui veut dire « tendre vers », « avoir l'intention de ».  D'où son sens de « vouloir » (quand on *veut* quelque chose, on *va vers* ce quelque chose)¹.  Du sens de « avoir l'intention » on est passé à « comprendre ».  *Le Dictionnaire Historique de La langue Française* (sld Alain Rey) dit qu'on est passé de  *comment l'entendez-vous ?*, qui voulait dire au 16<sup>e</sup> siècle : *quelles sont vos intentions ?*, à : *quel sens donnez-vous à cela ?* (c'est à dire *que comprenez-vous ?*).
*Intendere* en latin voulait aussi dire « percevoir par le sens de l'ouïe » mais « ouïr » est resté plus utilisé que « entendre » jusqu'au 17<sup>e</sup> siècle et de nos jours « ouïr » n'est pratiquement plus utilisé.

Dans l'expression « il en est ainsi… »  *en* est  pronom personnel.  Il n'a pas d'antécédent (un pronom relatif aurait un antécédent) il représente quelque chose qui n'est pas nommé dans la phrase que tu cites. En fait « il en est ainsi… » est une expression toute faite en français, c'est du langage soutenu, en langage courant on dirait « c'est ainsi ».

---

<sup>1</sup> On rapprochera ce sens de « entendre » de l'anglais *intend to* qui a bien sûr la même origine latine.

Answer (score 2):

Le mot *entendre* vient du mot latin [*intendere*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/intendo#la) qui signifie étymologiquement « tendre vers, se tourner vers » et de là au sens figuré « agir dans le but de », « avoir l'intention de », « viser à ». Dès le latin classique, le sens de « porter attention à » est apparu, et de là « comprendre » ainsi que « ouïr » en ancien français.

Les sens autre que « ouïr » ont essentiellement disparu en français moderne. On utilise néanmoins quelquefois *entendre* dans le sens de « comprendre » ou de « avoir l'intention » dans la langue soutenue. Voir l'article du [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entendre) (II et III) pour des exemples.

Dans ce texte juridique (une décision de justice, je pense), le mot *entendre* a ici un sens précis : il signifie que l'entité qui écrit ce texte fait référence non seulement aux directives telles qu'elles sont rédigées, mais aussi à l'intention du législateur qui les a rédigées et qui est sous-jacente au texte lui-même (sens « Vouloir quelque chose, avoir l'intention bien arrêtée de » du Larousse, III.B « Avoir la ferme intention, la volonté arrêtée de faire une chose » du TLF). Il s'agit ici de [directives européennes](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directive_de_l%27Union_europ%C3%A9enne), qui n'ont pas force de règlement : elles sont destinées à être transcrites dans la législation de chaque état. Elles ne valent donc pas par leur texte littéral, mais par leur intention. Le mot est également souvent appliqué pour des textes qui ont force de loi, pour signifier [l'intention du législateur](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22le+l%C3%A9gislateur+entend%22).

Pour le reste, voir [la réponse de Laure](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7811/sens-inopine-de-entendre/7813#7813).

Answer (score 1):

1- Depuis que Pierre Larousse, homme cultivé et intègre, est hélas disparu en 1875, je me garde bien de lire ceux qui exploitent son nom.

2- "Entendre" n'a aucun sens inattendu : du latin *intendere*, évidemment "tendre vers", le sens dominant jusqu'à la fin de l'époque classique a bien été de "comprendre", et je ne me souviens d'aucune citation classique où il aurait vraiment signifié "vouloir", mais certes par extension "d'ouïr".

3- Ce qui subsiste : "à qui veut bien entendre" signifie "qui est capable de comprendre", sans aucune référence à sa finesse d'oreille ; "ne pas l'entendre de cette oreille" est "ne pas être d'accord" ; "entendre raison" est "devenir sage" ; "laisser entendre" est "insinuer" - sans aucune idée de bouche à oreille(s) ; voir aussi "j'entends que l'on obéisse à mes ordres", "faites comme vous l'entendez", "cela s'entend" est "c'est évident", "il s'y entend en parfumerie" n'a aucun rapport avec l'audition, etc..
"S'entr'endre comme larrons en foire" est dans Corneille, et "S'entr'entendre" dans Montaigne.

4- Il n'y a pas d'antécédent dans l'exemple donné, que des sujets.

Comment: Merci. Plussoyé.